# One-to-many Using Bridge Table

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I'm setting up relationships between models and I'm wondering if there's any harm using a bridge table for a one-to-many relationship?

i.e. These are some of the models

- User
- Team
- Group

Each User may or may-not have a Team or Group. Would it be better to have nullable FK's in the User model for `team_id`, `group_id`, or is using bridge tables `team_user`, `group_user` acceptable? (There is little chance this will ever be a many-to-many relationship)

Would there be any ill effects in using a bridge table for one-to-many?

Answer (score 2):

A "bridge table" is usually used to model many-to-many. In your case, can a user be in more than one team or group? If so, a bridge table is what you want. If not, I'd go with nullable-FK's.

If you want the bridge table for one-to-many you should use a unique index to ensure you only have "one."

Now nulls themselves are the subject of some religious wars. There are good arguments to avoid them. In this case, I think they're ok - it means 0 (fk is NULL) or 1 (fk points to the team or group the user belongs to.)